# Mocking a static method with different arguments and different results

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a static class Exec with method doSomething(for)

Now i want to mock it for following 2 invocations in order or any order on by one.

```
Exec.stub(:doSomthing).with('a').and_return('called with a')
Exec.stub(:doSomthing).with('b').and_return('called with b')
```

Am getting error

```
Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

How do i resolve it?

Note :This above code is just pseudocode and not my real code

Comment: Note that in Ruby you should have method names of the form `do_something` as capitals are reserved for `ClassName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` situations.

Comment: Do you need to call `Exec.stub(:doSomthing) { }` first?

Comment: No, only Exec.doSomething('a) and Exec.doSoemthing('b') calls are expectd, so i  justed trained for those two calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
allow(Exec).to receive(:doSomthing).with('a').and_return('called with a')
allow(Exec).to receive(:doSomthing).with('b').and_return('called with b')
```

use `expect` instead of `allow` if you need your spec to fail when the method was not called at all.